# In Superset what is Database "main" used for?

Tags: apache-superset

We have an installation, which created the database "main" in the datasource list. When we changed to an older DB backup, the user was having a wrong password (and thus "test connection" was failing).

Nevertheless Superset kept working. So it used the config user from MySQL connection we defined.

Now the question: What is "main" DB used for? Can we securely delete it?

Comment: Superset has one tag that should be used: [tag:apache-superset]. The other is ambiguous and being removed from all questions because there is no reason to have two tags for the same thing. Please do not re-add bad tags.

Comment: @TylerH Wouldn‘t it make sense to delete the superset tag rather than editing zillions of questions? Second: I cannot see it‘s tagged deprecated. Third: IMHO I‘d simply use the synonym functionality for tags in SO. You might be able to add it with your reputation ;-)

Comment: Removing tags from questions is how tags get deleted. And no, I can't unilaterally synonymize superset to apache-superset. Not only would that be bad (since superset is a mathematical term that is used in some questions totally unrelated to the apache product), I also need several other users to vote on it (which may take years to do) and it requires that I have a significant amount of tag score for the tag, which I do not. FYI, if you hover over tags you can see their wiki excerpts, which include usage guidance. You should always read tag wiki excerpts before using them.